# How change the image name and save it, when i uploading an image to s3 using boto3

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

How change the image name and save it, when i uploading an image to s3 using boto3.

ex) datetime.jpg

pleas help....

```
@app.route('/fileupload', methods=['POST'])
def file_upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                      aws_access_key_id="mykey",
                      aws_secret_access_key="myaccesskey"
                      )
    s3.put_object(
        ACL="public-read",
        Bucket="burket",
        Body=file,
        Key=file.filename,
        ContentType=file.content_type)
    print(url)
    return jsonify({'result': 'success'})
```

```
function save() {
    let form_data = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/fileupload',
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success!");
        },
    });
}
```

I think we can use this code.
But it couldn't be used.

```
extension = file.filename.split('.')[-1]
today = datetime.now()
mytime = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

filename = f'file-{mytime}'
```

Comment: Supply whatever Key parameter you like when calling put_object. You don't have to use the uploaded filename.

Comment: The `Key` parameter exists for this exact same purpose - there is *no need* to rename the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename objects after uploading into s3.

```
client.copy_object(Bucket="BucketName", CopySource="BucketName/OriginalName", Key="NewName")
client.delete_object(Bucket="BucketName", Key="OriginalName")
```